# Joint distribution of independent discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Suppose I have two independent discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ described by the distributions:

$\mathbb{P}(X= k) = p_k$ for $k=1,\dots, K_X$

$\mathbb{P}(Y= k) = q_k$ for $k=1,\dots, K_Y$.

We can create vectors $u_X = [p_1, p_2, \dots, p_{K_X}]$ and $u_Y = [q_1, q_2, \dots, q_{K_Y}]$ that describe the probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Does the $K_X\times K_Y$ matrix  $u_X^\top u_Y$ encode the joint distribution $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, it does. Just try to expand the matrix product and you'll find that each one of the rows of the resulting matrix give probabilities corresponding a constant value of $X$ and each one of the columns give the probabilities corresponding to a constant value of $Y$.